How do I stop my front brake disc rubbing
How do I stop my front brake disc rubbing ( Shimano R8710 )

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It would help if you add more details to your question, like what you've already tried and a photo of the brake.

Many thanks  for responding . I had removed the wheel and must have pressed the brake handle because I could not refit the disk into the brakes when I tried to refit the wheel. I read another response on the site about easing out the brakes pistons with a credit card. Worked a treat but left me with scraping brakes when I refitted the wheel, hence my question. However after  a  short shakeout ride it seems to have self - corrected so think I’m ok now

You could add the first post of your comment to clarify your question and the second part as a self-answer... Maybe also take the https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour and have a look at the https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help pages.

Since you removed the wheel, its possible the axle is not fully seated in the dropouts and things are just a little bit out of position.
Try loosening the axle with the bike normal-way-up and tyres on the ground, then retightening the axle.
If that doesn't help, the rotor may have been warped in the past so hand-spin the wheel while looking closely at the pad/rotor gap to see if it changes and rubs.
